# Can I get vertex's coordinates result of cloth simulation?

Tags: vertices, cloth-simulation, vertex-groups, coordinates

*blender version==2.9.*
I want to get vertex coordinates result of cloth simulation(with python script, if I could).
Now, although I could get the vertex coordinates, they are before cloth simulation.

```
v_world = v.co @ obj.matrix_world
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(
                 type='ARROWS',
                 location=v_world)
```

[image: cHPPU.png]
[image: cHPPU.png]

can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dependendy graph to do that (supposing the simulation is already baked):

```
import bpy
import bmesh


# Set the frame considered as the result of the sim
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 30

# Get the dependency graph state for this frame
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

# The object
obj = bpy.context.object

# The mesh from the object and dependency graph
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_object(obj, dg)

# Take the coordinates
for v in bm.verts:
    print(v.co)

del bm
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

I could get an shape result of cloth simulation by following script,

```
(already cloth modifier is set)
bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True)
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply_as_shapekey(keep_modifier=False, modifier='Cloth')
bpy.context.object.use_shape_key_edit_mode = True
bpy.data.shape_keys['Key'].key_blocks['Cloth'].value = 1
```

But, still I got same coordinates before result of cloth simulation.
I can edit vertices of resulting cloth simulation, so, I think I could get vertex result of this as same...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @lemon , this is the best way I think.

I found another way to get vertex resulting cloth simulation, so share this.

Before running code,
I've added 'Plane' and set vertex groups named 'Group' and 'Target'
('Group': to pin cloth, 'Target': target vertex)

```
def add_modifier(obj):
    """Add cloth modifier and apply as shapekey
    Args:
       obj(bpy.data.objects): object for cloth simulation
                              (In this case, 'Plane')
    
    Returns:
      shapekey
    """
    for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        ob.select_set(False)
    obj.select_set(True)
    
    # add modifier and set some properties
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CLOTH')
    modifier = obj.modifiers['Cloth']
    modifier.collision_settings.use_collision = True
    modifier.settings.bending_model = 'LINEAR'
    modifier.settings.vertex_group_mass = 'Group'
    
    # bake cloth simulation to get last frame
    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True)
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(250)

    # apply cloth modifier as shape-key
    #  and set value as '1'(last frame)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply_as_shapekey(keep_modifier=False, modifier='Cloth')
    bpy.context.object.use_shape_key_edit_mode = True
    shapekey = bpy.data.shape_keys['Key'].key_blocks['Cloth']
    shapekey.value = 1.0
    return shapekey


# main
obj = bpy.data.objects['Plane']

# get vertices belong to vertex geoup named 'Target'
vg = obj.vertex_groups.get('Target')
vlist = []
for v in obj.data.vertices:
   for g in v.groups:
        if g.group == vg.index:
             vlist.append(v)

shapekey = add_modifier(obj)

for v in vlist:
    v_world = shapekey.data[v.index].co @ obj.matrix_world
    # visualize with ARROW
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='ARROWS', location=v_world)
```

if someone know better ways or scripts, let me know please.